# inotifywait not working with Visual Studio Code

Tags: inotify

I tried to make myself a small shell script that would watch for file changes using `inotifywait` and copy modified/created files and delete deleted files to some destination folder (or `rsync` specific file). I was not able to make this work.

Investigation: `inotifywait` is able to detect modifications when I'm editing/deleting/creating files using `nano`/`vim`/`touch`/`rm`. The problem emerges when I modify/create/delete a file using Visual Studio Code. When I try to `watch -d stat some_file`, I can see all the modifications happening even when using Visual Studio Code.

I'm not able to figure out what's the problem since I'm not super familiar with Linux.

I would like to be able to use `inotifywait` since I want to watch for changes in nearly 28000 files. I don't want to use some hybrid of `watch`, `ls`, `find`, `stat` since iterating whole dir recursively is slow on Virtual Box shared folder. Also `fs.inotify.max_user_watches` was increased to a sufficient number.

To be complete, here is simplified used command:

```
$ inotifywait --monitor --recursive /share/repo/
```